# How to display 1.250 as 1.25, and 1.256 as 1.256 in the same field in MVC, via a Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am sure this is a simple one.

I am using MVC3 ASP.NET 4.5, C#, Razor, SQL Server 200, EF6

I have a DB column that is defined at decimal 18,3. If I have a value of 1.256 I realise this will display, via a Razor View, as 1.256. However if I have a value of 1.250 then my client has expressed a wish to display this as 1.25 and not 1.250. Is this possible and if so how?

My code is typically:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DecimalValue1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [General ("G") Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=VS.90).aspx#GFormatString) to format your `decimal` values as you want. `"G29"` overload is exactly what you need.

But you can't use  `.ToString` with `DisplayFor` helper. So i recomended to add additional right formated field in your `ViewModel` as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598999/1849444).

So your final solution can be like this:

In `ViewModel`:

```
public string FormattedDecimalValue1
{
    get
    {
        return this.DecimalValue1.ToString("G29");
    }
}
```

And on `View`:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FormattedDecimalValue1)
```

Comment: Is it possible to define this as part of the data format attribute for a property ie [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:G29}")]